# Symfony 2 through Vagrant on Windows has errors, because Symfony tries to look for twig files using a mish-mash of Windows and Linux paths

Tags: php, symfony, twig, vagrant, twig-extension

Whenever I try to access (almost) any page/route, I get errors like:

> ContextErrorException in Filesystem.php line 130: 
>   Warning:
>   file_get_contents(C:_CODE\symfony2\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle/Resources/views/Configurator/Step/doctrine.html.twig):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Basically, Symfony seems to be piecing together URLs from both the Vagrant/Linux and Windows environments, and thus is unable to find a bunch of twig files.

**A little about my setup:**

I have my Symfony files on the Windows machine, and they are mapped onto the Vagrant box. I'm just taking advantage of the default "." -> "/vagrant" mapping, and then have the puppet config create a symlink from "/vagrant/web" -> "/var/www" ("." is where both Symfony and the vagrantfile are located). The setup is basically copied from https://github.com/nater1067/Vagrant-Symfony-2. Just to make sure it wasn't me, I used the "stock" git pull from that repo, and went to http://localhost/config (after commenting out the restriction that only allows connections from localhost), and that error above showed up on step 2.

**What I've tried:**

As you can see from the repo's puppet file, it seems to already properly set the owner of the web files (/var/www/*) to vagrant:vagrant. I've also tried mapping the entire C drive to /vagrant/c. and then using a symlink to get the correct ../%Symfony%/web files into /var/www, but that didn't work either. I've also tried setting the permissions to 777 for all directories and files under /var/www.

**The question:**

Is there something else I need to do with a Windows/Vagrant/Symfony setup to make sure Symfony doesn't try to piece together Linux and Windows paths? My next step is to just give up, and sftp the files from Windows to the vagrant box.

Comment: Are you executing any symfony commands on your local machine? Basically you should just edit files through your IDE and everything else should be on vagrant machine. Symfony by itself will never be aware of the fact that there is another OS involved. As long as you run everything from the virtual machine this should never happen.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I just needed to run a `php app/console cache:clear` within vagrant, and that did the trick. I'm glad I didn't have to resort to auto uploads. Also, I'm not sure how to mark your comment as the correct answer. If you want to re-reply as an answer, I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you executing any symfony commands on your local machine? Basically you should just edit files through your IDE and everything else should be on vagrant machine. Symfony by itself will never be aware of the fact that there is another OS involved. As long as you run everything from the virtual machine this should never happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply reverse your configuration. Put your Symfony files inside your Vagrant box; next, using some kind of network sharing, use something to edit them outside.

This has just one single disadvantage: the connection to your Vagrant box could be slow, especially using NFS for sharing.

Comment: That was going to be my next step, but I want to keep everything as easy and straightforward as possible, especially for future me or a future dev that inherits this project.

Comment: That IS easy, because you isolate your project from you Windows system. It runs in a virtual machine that simulate the product environment

Comment: Sorry, maybe easy wasn't the right word. It's certainly very easy, but it's just more steps to get future devs up and going.